# ASP.NET "stacked" regular expression field validators

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have 2 ASP.NET regular expression validators:

1. `^\s*[-+.'\w]+@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$` check whether the email address is valid
2. `@(adres.pl|vp.pl)` check if value contains any of these strings

The problem now is:
The strings in bullet 2 above should NOT be allowed, so o email address "john@adres.pl" should not be allowed.

However, the validators are only positive, meaning that they check if they DO contain the structure.
So when someone currently enters "test@test.com", I get "invalid value"

My code below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="emailinvalid" ValidationExpression="^\s*[-+.'\w]+@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$" ID="rev1" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="not allowed" ValidationExpression="@(adres.pl|vp.pl)" ID="rev2" runat="server"/>
```

I was initially thinking of combining expressions 1 and 2, but then I wouldn't know which one fails, and don't know which error to display.

What I would expect is:

- "35435gd" -> emailinvalid
- "john@adres.pl" -> not allowed
- "john@gmail.com" -> all validators are ok

Or perhaps validator `rev2` should only execute if `rev1` does not throw an error, so "stacking" for a lack of a better term, which a: seems cumbersome and b: I wouldn't know how to do it.

How can I solve for this?

**UPDATE 1**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="invalid" ValidationExpression="^\s*[-+.'\w]+@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$" ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="not allowed" ValidationExpression="@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)" ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server"/>
```

"gddg" results in "not allowed", whereas I'd expect "invalid".

When I switch the order of these validators, both errors "invalid" and "not allowed" show.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="invalid" ValidationExpression="^\s*[-+.'\w]+@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$" ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="not allowed" ValidationExpression="@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)" ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single pattern and you might write your existing pattern as:

```
^\s*[-+.'\w]+@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$
```

The part excluding either `adres.pl` or `vp.pl` can be written as `@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)` excluding those matches directly after the @.

You could also use `@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\s*$)` if that is the last part of the email address just like you currently do for this part `\.(?!co\s*$)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6aQoNo/1).

**Note** that your pattern would allow leading and trailing whitespace chars for the e-mail address.

Comment: Thanks, that expression works. I tried adding that in a single validator, but it would result in an unclear message to the user: either the email address is syntactically incorrect OR the email address is not allowed (because of my email provider exclusion rule). I need to know which of these 2 expressions failed to ensure I can communicate clearly to the end user.

Comment: @Adam The pattern can either match or fail, in that case you would have to use 2 patterns or 1 check to see if the string contains adres.pl or vp.pl.

Comment: Thanks again. It's that 2nd part where I'm struggling. I want the 2nd validator to FAIL if the value contains `@adres.pl`. 
The validator currently returns true if the value contains "@adres.pl". I think what I need is to invert the outcome of this expression, e.g. NOT("expression contains @adres.pl"). How would I do that? `!` operator apparently is not the inverse in regex.

Comment: @Adam Did you try just `@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)` for the second validator. It will return true if  adres.pl or vp.pl is not there.

Comment: I did, please see my update 1.

Comment: @Adam What if you use the whole pattern `^\s*[-+.'\w]+@(?!(?:adres|vp)\.pl\b)\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.(?!co\s*$)\w{2,}\s*$` for the second validator? Perhaps you can use a clickhandler for the second validator and take the string value from the source that you want to validate and do a string should not contain check and manually set if the check if valid or not?

Comment: Ended up with a custom validator indeed, thanks!